# How can I decode this EDID string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding

I have a file. It appears to be in binary character set.

```
$ file -bi /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1/edid
inode/x-empty; charset=binary
```

It is not helpful to call `File.read`

```
filepath = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1/edid'
File.read(filepath)
# => "\u0000\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\u0000\u0004i\xA3'e\f\u0000\u0000\u0006\u0018\u0001\u0004\xA5<\"x:\xA5\x95\xAATO\xA1&\nPT\xB7\xEF\u0000\xD1\xC0\xB3\u0000\x95\u0000\x81\x80\x81@\x81\u0000\x81\xC0qOV^\u0000\xA0\xA0\xA0)P0 5\u0000UP!\u0000\u0000\u001A\u0000\u0000\u0000\xFF\u0000E2LMTF003173\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\xFD\u0000\u0018L\u0018c\u001E\u0004\u0011\u0001@\xF88\xF0<\u0000\u0000\u0000\xFC\u0000ASUS PB278\n  \u0001\xF2\u0002\u0003\"qO\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0004\u0014\u0005\u001F\x90\u000E\u000F\u001D\u001E#\t\u0017\a\x83\u0001\u0000\u0000en\f\u0000\u0010\u0000\x8C\nЊ \xE0-\u0010\u0010>\x96\u0000UP!\u0000\u0000\u0018\u0001\u001D\u0000rQ\xD0\u001E n(U\u0000UP!\u0000\u0000\u001E\u0001\u001D\u0000\xBCR\xD0\u001E \xB8(U@UP!\u0000\u0000\u001E\x8C\nА @1 \f@U\u0000UP!\u0000\u0000\u0018\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\x96"
```

Reading it as binary is not helpful

```
File.open(filepath, 'rb').read
# => "\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x00\x04i\xA3'e\f\x00\x00\x06\x18\x01\x04\xA5<\"x:\xA5\x95\xAATO\xA1&\nPT\xB7\xEF\x00\xD1\xC0\xB3\x00\x95\x00\x81\x80\x81@\x81\x00\x81\xC0qOV^\x00\xA0\xA0\xA0)P0 5\x00UP!\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x00\xFF\x00E2LMTF003173\n\x00\x00\x00\xFD\x00\x18L\x18c\x1E\x04\x11\x01@\xF88\xF0<\x00\x00\x00\xFC\x00ASUS PB278\n  \x01\xF2\x02\x03\"qO\x01\x02\x03\x11\x12\x13\x04\x14\x05\x1F\x90\x0E\x0F\x1D\x1E#\t\x17\a\x83\x01\x00\x00en\f\x00\x10\x00\x8C\n\xD0\x8A \xE0-\x10\x10>\x96\x00UP!\x00\x00\x18\x01\x1D\x00rQ\xD0\x1E n(U\x00UP!\x00\x00\x1E\x01\x1D\x00\xBCR\xD0\x1E \xB8(U@UP!\x00\x00\x1E\x8C\n\xD0\x90 @1 \f@U\x00UP!\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x96"

puts File.open(filepath, 'rb').read
```

outputs:

```
������i�'e
          �<"x:���TO�&
PT���������@���qOV^���)P0 5UP!��E2LMTF003173
�Lc@�8�<�ASUS PB278
  �"qO�#    �en
                   �
Њ �->�UP!rQ� n(UUP!�R� �(U@UP!�
А @1 
     @UUP!�
```

I tried this as well

```
puts File.open(filepath, "r:ISO-8859-1:UTF-8", &:read)
```

which outputs:

```
ÿÿÿÿÿÿi£'e
          ¥<"x:¥ªTO¡&
PT·ïÑÀ³@ÀqOV^   )P0 5UP!�ÿE2LMTF003173
ýLc@ø8ð<üASUS PB278
  ò"qOen

Ð à->UP!rQÐ n(UUP!¼RÐ ¸(U@UP!
Ð
```

[rchardet](https://github.com/jmhodges/rchardet) is not helpful either.

```
CharDet.detect File.open(filepath, 'rb').read
# => {"encoding"=>nil, "confidence"=>0.0}
```

Comment: I was thinking that too but none of the formats seem to return a useful result.

Comment: Use `Encoding::BINARY` and literally read byte by byte as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data#EDID_1.4_data_format). Thank God not _everything_ is already available in gems, some development is still possible once a year.

Comment: I started this project https://github.com/HarlemSquirrel/edid-rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EDID is a binary format and there seems to be no gem available to parse it, I would recommend using the [bindata](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata) gem to create a model of the data as described on the [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data#EDID_1.4_data_format) wikipedia page.

For the couple of first fields it would be something like:

```
require 'bindata'

module EDID
  class Record < BinData::Record
    HEADER_BYTES = [0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00]
    array :header_bytes, type: :uint8, initial_length: 8, value: HEADER_BYTES, assert_value: HEADER_BYTES
    bit1 :manufacturer_id_pad, value: 0
    array :manufacturer_id, type: :bit5, initial_length: 3
    uint16le :product_code
    uint32le :serial_number
    uint8 :manufacture_week
    uint8 :manufacture_year
    uint8 :edid_version, initial_value: 1
    uint8 :edid_revision, initial_value: 3

    def manufacturer
      manufacturer_id.map { |int| (int+64).chr }.join
    end

    def manufacture_year_real
      manufacture_week == 255 ? manufacture_year : (manufacture_year + 1990)
    end

    def to_s
      <<~EOB
        Manufacturer: #{manufacturer}
        Product: #{product_code}
        Serial: #{serial_number}
        Manufacture_year: #{manufacture_year_real}
        Manufacture_week: #{manufacture_week == 255 ? 'unknown' : manufacture_week}
      EOB
    end
  end
end
```

And using it with your data:

```
io = File.open('/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1/edid')
record = EDID::Record.read(io)
puts record
```

Outputs:

```
Manufacturer: ACI
Product: 10147
Serial: 3173
Manufacture_year: 2014
Manufacture_week: 6
```